# UIScrollView and keyboard iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I'm developing an app for iPad in which I've a form in a scroll view view several `UITextField`.
In this form I've much than a `UITextField` in one row like so:

[image]

So when the keyboard is closed and I tap on "Via" `UITextField` with the following methods:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    float bottom = 0.0;
    bottom = kbSize.height;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, bottom + 50, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;

    aRect.size.height -= bottom + 50;

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y - (scrollView.frame.size.height - kbSize.width - 10));
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    activeField = nil;
}
```

everything works fine and scroll view moves up to show the `UITextField` I'm editing.
When the keyboard is opened and I tap on "CAP" `UITextField` the scroll view scrolls up and the `UITextField` runs up outside of the view.
I'm asking you how I can avoid this behavior.

NOTE:I will not use external library to do that!

Thank you

Comment: I think you have to try this code for up the scrollview    - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, textField.frame.origin.y-120);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
}

Comment: you have to set the first UItextField size instead of 120

Comment: if my answer is work for you then tell me so i can post it

Answer (score 0):

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
```

> As per the apple documentation the automaticAdjustScrollViewInsets by
>   default YES.
>
> So its trying to control your scrollview.
>
> add this in your viewdidload method and then try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution,

If you don't want to write any lines of code for managing keyboard based on textField within scrollview then simply use this given below third party library which will automatically manage your textfield with keyboard.

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Hope it will work for u.

Comment: Look at update of my question... I will not use any external library to my app!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by reading this [link in Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), so in my case the code is the follow:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height + 50 , 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Thank you for answering me